# How does one best group and render items, like with an "interest" property that might be equal amongst many "User" instances?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, reduce

Hello Everyone I am having some problems trying to make a function. As shown in the code. I want to make the interestMatch function. What the function needs to do is to look at all the Users and find those users that have the same interest - bob and jack in my code. I think it should be something with an if statement. Kinda: "if any users have the same interest" "return this user and this user is a match!"
Can someone help me!?
Thanks a lot!

````
class User {
    constructor(username, password, firstname, lastname, email, birthday, gender, interest){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interest = interest
    }
}
let InterrestArray = ["Netflix", "Sports", "Party", "Business", "Children", "Hygge"]

let bob = new User ("bob123", "12345", "Bob", "bobiski", "bob@bob.com", "2000-10-10", "male", interrest[0]);
let jack = new User ("jack20", "340302", "Jack", "jackiski", "jack@jack.com", "2000-06-10", "male", interrest[0]);
let thif = new User ("thif20", "204903", "Thifanny", "Thifiski", "thif@jack.com", "2000-09-12", "famale", interrest[1]);

function interestMatch(){
???
}

console.log(interestMatch())
// I want it to console.log - "bob maches with jack!" - because the have the same interrest
```
````

Comment: are there any open questions?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be to have two nested `for` loops which iterate over the users and compares their interest:

```
function interestMatch(users){
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const user1 = users[i];
    // No need to iterate over any user that comes "before" user1.
    for (let j = i+1; j < users.length; j++) {
      const user2 = users[j];
      if (user1.interest === user2.interest) {
        return `${user1.username} matches with ${user2.username}`;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course things get more complex if users can have multiple interests or if you want to return all matches. In that case it might make sense to create an `interest -> list of users` map.

Answer (score 0):

Any approach the OP is looking for is a little bit more complex than

> *it should be something with an if statement*.

A valid approach was to scan through a list of users, look up each of a user's interest and push the user into its interest related array. Thus the base approach creates an `interest` based map or index with interest-specific user-lists.

This was just the first part, providing an approach that creates a data structure which can be processed further.

With the needed data structure at hand (a key value store, where `interest` is key and a specific user-list is each key's value) one approaches the second part which is about output/rendering.

For each key-value pair (interest and user list) one does invoke a user list specific render function. Within this step one also does map the `user` list into a list of e.g. each of a user's first name.

The final render function then needs to take care of the edge cases ... like ... there is a single user, with an interest which is not shared by anyone else ... or ... there are more than two users who have one and the same interest in common ...

```js
class User {
  constructor(
    username, password, firstname, lastname,
    email, birthday, gender, interest
  ) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      username, password, firstname, lastname,
      email, birthday, gender, interest
    });
  }
}

function groupUserByInterest(index, user) {
  const { interest } = user;
  const sameInterestList = index[interest] || (index[interest] = []);

  sameInterestList.push(user);
  return index;
}

const interestList = ["Netflix", "Sports", "Party", "Business", "Children", "Hygge"];

const userList = [
  new User ("bob123", "12345", "Bob", "bobiski", "bob@bob.com", "2000-10-10", "male", interestList[0]),
  new User ("jack20", "340302", "Jack", "jackiski", "jack@jack.com", "2000-06-10", "male", interestList[0]),
  new User ("jane20", "340303", "Jane", "janinski", "jane@jane.com", "2000-06-10", "famale", interestList[0]),
  new User ("thif20", "204903", "Thifanny", "Thifiski", "thif@jack.com", "2000-09-12", "famale", interestList[1])
];

// const [ bob, jack, jane, thif ] = userList;

function renderUsersOfSameInterest(interest, userList) {
  const [ first, ...rest ] = userList;
  let template;
  if (!rest.length) {

    template = `There is no other user who matches ${ first }'s interest (${ interest }).`;
  } else {
    template = `${ first }'s interest (${ interest }) maches with the one of ${ rest.join(' and ') }!`;
  }
  console.log(template);
}
function renderUsersOfSameInterestsByFirstname(index) {
  Object.entries(index).forEach(([interest, userList]) =>
    renderUsersOfSameInterest(interest, userList.map(user =>
      user.firstname))
  );
  // console.log('index', index);
}

renderUsersOfSameInterestsByFirstname(
  userList.reduce(groupUserByInterest, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```